# HTTP to HTTPS redirecting static to dynamic URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

We have added an HTTP to HTTPS redirect rule in the htaccess file....

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

In general that works fine but when its applied to the rewritten URLs in the subfolder it converts that back to dynamic URLs
e.g.

http://www.domain.co.uk/make/model/ would be converted to https://www.domain.co.uk/product.php?make=htc&model=onem9

We really need the URL just to move directly to https://

Comment: Show the rule that converts `/make/model` to `?make=htc&model=onem9`?

Comment: I simplified the question to help but here is the actual rule ....

RewriteBase /mobiles/
RewriteRule ^deals/(.*)/([^/]*)\/$ /category-list1-2.php?manufacturer=$1&handsetname=$2&networks=any [L]

Answer (score 0):

I use the following, which has always worked well for me:

```
# force HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: The http to https rule works fine its just that the other rewritten urls get converted back to dynamic urls at when they are redirect from http to https

Comment: @Samtex9 hence the `{REQUEST_URI}` bit... Maybe your ordering is off. The HTTPS rule should be before the path rewrite.

Comment: the https rule is in the parent folder of the page rewrite rule

Comment: @Samtex9 I wouldn't expect a parent folder's htaccess rules to execute, only the current folder. Not sure what other information to provide since I cannot reproduce the problem on my end.

Comment: I am getting hits to this url.... https://www.mymo.co.uk/category-list1-2.php?handsetname=galaxy-s6-edge-32gb-black&manufacturer=samsung When is should be ... https://www.mymo.co.uk/mobiles/deals/samsung/galaxy-s6-edge-32gb-black/   ... Use this url to recreate the problem ..... http://www.mymo.co.uk/mobiles/deals/samsung/galaxy-s6-edge-32gb-black/